# How to scale iframe

Tags: css, angularjs, iframe, scale

I've been trying to scale an iframe using angular with the panzoom dependency but  it dosen't work properly with iframe. I need another method/solution to scale and zoom an iframe.

```
<panzoom config="config" model="model" style="width:800px; height: 800px">
  <iframe src="https://stackoverflow.com/"
    frameborder="0" width="580" height="500" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</panzoom>
```

Comment: I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166160/how-can-i-scale-the-content-of-an-iframe). Hope this works out for you:)

Comment: I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166160/how-can-i-scale-the-content-of-an-iframe). Hope this works out for you:)