# How to set auto zoom

Tags: html, iframe, zooming

Hey I have a code that is iframed by the code on the iframe is set at 640x460 and I'm wanting to fit 4 of them on a page. So I'm wanting to make the page when it's loaded the zoom be set from 100% to 50% by default and, if the user wants that changed, they can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd>. I've tried everything. Any help on this would be GREAT.

Here is what I've tried:

```
<html>
<style>
  #MyDiv>*
   {
        zoom: 50%;
        -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
   }
</style>
<MyDiv>

<h2>Norwegian Mountain Trip</h2>
<iframe src="iframeurl" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="no" frameborder="0" width="642" height="460" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" ></iframe>

</MyDiv>
</html>
```

Comment: Tried this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166160/how-can-i-scale-the-content-of-an-iframe)?