# Is it possible change the scale of the redirected page?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I redirected to "b.php" using below code.

```
<body onLoad="document.newform.submit();">
    <form name='newform' action='http://receive/b.php' method='post' >
        <input type='hidden' name='terminal'    value='android'>
        <input type='hidden' name='customername'    value='foo'>
    </form>
</body>
```

But the scale of "b.php" page is high, so i want to reduce it.
And I can't change the "b.php" because it is on the other server.
Is there any method change the scale of "b.php" page without modify source of "b"?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: For security reasons, that is completely impossible without cooperation.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Is it possible if i use iframe tag?

Comment: <input type='hidden' name='scale' value='2'>

Comment: iframe yes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166160/how-can-i-scale-the-content-of-an-iframe

Comment: Only if the other site allows framing.

Comment: Thanks for answer, Andrew.
Thanks for answer, SLaks.