# Github - how to find all files modified in the last X days in an organization across all repos?

Tags: github, github-api

I work at a company that runs a private instance of Github, and we have hundreds of repos in a single organization.

I'd like to obtain a list of files that were modified in the last X days, regardless of which repo it was modified in.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never found a way to do this exactly, and strongly suspect it's never going to work with a 3rd party website.

I did however realize that you can scale the contents of an iframe to fit the iframe, which works for me

This seems to be the best stackoverflow on it

[How can I scale the content of an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166160/how-can-i-scale-the-content-of-an-iframe)

Here's an example that works in Chrome and Safari (modern) but not sure about Firefox or older browsers. It shows a website embedded in an iframe, and scaled to fit the iframe size.

```css
.wrap { width: 320px; height: 196px; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; float: left;}
.frame { width: 1280px; height: 786px; border: 1px solid black}

.frame {
    // zoom: 0.25;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.25);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform: scale(0.25);
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.25);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<p>before the iframe</p>
<div class="wrap">

<div class="wrap">
    <iframe class="frame" src="https://time.is">
    </iframe>
</div>
```