# Can an iframe with a dynamic html menu have it's menu show outside the iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I've got a web page that has an iframe in it from a 3rd party web app.

The web app in the iframe has a dynamic popup menu that gets cut off at the edge of the iframe.

Is there anyway I can embed the iframe so it's allowed to show this dynamic menu outside the borders of the iframe? I fully trust the 3rd party website, but can't change any of it's code.

I doubt it's possible, as I think it'd be a security issue (clickjacking), but want to be sure.

Here's a pic of the issue, with black being the iframe border, and the red rectangle being the part that's getting cut off.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found a way to do this exactly, and strongly suspect it's never going to work with a 3rd party website.

I did however realize that you can scale the contents of an iframe to fit the iframe, which works for me

This seems to be the best stackoverflow on it

[How can I scale the content of an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166160/how-can-i-scale-the-content-of-an-iframe)

Here's an example that works in Chrome, Safari and Firefox (modern) but not sure about older browsers. It shows a website embedded in an iframe, and scaled to fit the iframe size.

```css
.wrap { width: 320px; height: 196px; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; float: left;}
.frame { width: 1280px; height: 786px; border: 1px solid black}

.frame {
    // zoom: 0.25;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.25);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform: scale(0.25);
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.25);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<p>before the iframe</p>
<div class="wrap">

<div class="wrap">
    <iframe class="frame" src="https://time.is">
    </iframe>
</div>
```