# Force resolution in iframe that has media queries

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, media-queries

Is there a way to force a specific resolution in an iframe that contains media queries?

I have an iframe in my page with the size of 300x200px and I'd like it to match the media queries as if it was 1000x500px without changing its size.

Comment: You can probably achieve this with CSS (scale()). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166160/how-can-i-scale-the-content-of-an-iframe

Comment: @BrettGregson I need that the content of this iframe matches the media queries for a specific resolution, not to change the size of its content.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adjust width and height of iframe to fit with content in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819416/adjust-width-and-height-of-iframe-to-fit-with-content-in-it)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you're asking. The content of the iframe is going to render according to the size of the iframe. Make the iframe whatever size you need (ie: 1000x500) and use scale to render it at 300x200.

Comment: @BrettGregson I'd like that media queries within this iframe matches a specific resolution (without changing the size of the iframe), like colors, padding, etc.

Comment: So you want the iframe to look like it's 1000x500, but display at 300x200?

Comment: Kind of like this: https://jsfiddle.net/cmvy1ohn/

Comment: @BrettGregson I don't want to scale it. I want it to match the media queries for a bigger screen size.

Comment: But you want it to display smaller? That's scaling

Comment: Have a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lc2byrau/ and https://jsfiddle.net/fs8vn4ua/. You see what I'm saying? The first iframe is rendering at 1200px, the second at 600px. You could adjust the scale value to ensure they're displaying the same size

Comment: @BrettGregson Let's imagine that we have a media query to set the background to red for a desktop display. If we render it at 200x300, you won't see this red background. And I want to see it at any size! (I cannot change this media queries)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197168/discussion-between-brett-gregson-and-emi).