# Is there an alternative to HTMLIFrameElement.zoom()?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe, zooming

The function HTMLIFrameElement.zoom() was removed from firefox, and the website itself says that [it is unlikely that it ever be supported again](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Gecko/Chrome/API/Browser_API/zoom). Is there an alternative way to change the zoom of an iframe?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I scale the content of an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166160/how-can-i-scale-the-content-of-an-iframe)

Comment: NO, it does not answer my question. The methods there are quite old already and many of the replies are "I don't think it is possible".