# How do I focus/center my webpage in a text/html type object tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, object

I'm currently creating a webpage where all my projects made are placed in cards. In these cards, I'm trying to show a mini version of the projects in the webpage before they click See Project:

[image: cards]

Those above the project names are just screenshots of the page. Yes they're the same as I've only placed one image source for now.

What I want to achieve is: instead of images, I want to show an interactive mini webpage of the same size (or a bit bigger).

So I used object tag and referenced it to the other page: (The buttons went outside the card but I'll fix them later!)

[image: objecttag]

The table is interactive as planned but it's not centering on the table from the other webpage which is what I wanted to show. I also cannot scroll it downwards or sidewards, only the table which has a scroll bar can be scrolled but that's it. Is there a way for this to be centered or at least scrollable?

This is the only code I used for the object tag:

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto; width:100%; height:400px; border: 1px solid #fff;">
    <object type="text/html" data="P/ST/home.html"
        style="width:100%; height:100%;">
    </object>
</div>
```

I've tried placing overflow: scroll; on the object but it didn't work, I also didn't think it would work but I had to try at least.

Comment: I suspect that the problem lies in the code of the page you are trying to embed, for example the table has a fixed width, or a minimum width that does not fit inside the card, if you could upload a working example I could give you more help in this regard.

Comment: why use an object tag and not an iframe?

Comment: Hello @cloned , iFrame seems to have solved my issue. While studying more with webpages, object was the first one I landed on so I used object, but then you guys gave me iFrame and now it solved it. Thanks so much again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For I understand you want to place an `<iframe>` element in your card to show your projects in 'live mode' .

I research about `<object>` element and [found](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp) :

> To embed a picture, it is better to use the `<img>` tag.
>
> To embed HTML, it is better to use the `<iframe>` tag.
>
> To embed video or audio, it is better to use the `<video>` and `<audio>`
> tags.

I tried to work with but did not succeed at all. What I got is manage the start position of the page inside the `<object>`. Just passing an id of element to be focused (like we did in links to focus certain areas). Works with local document / URL.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Object</title>
<style>
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    outline: none;
    font-family: 'Poppins', 'system-ui', 'sans-serif';
    font-weight: 300;
    transition: .3s linear 0s all;
}
body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="margin: 0 auto; width:100%; height:400px; border: 1px solid #fff;">
            <object type="text/html" data="https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#theming"
            style="width:100%; height:100%;">
        </object>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Most of external pages won't work with it because the `<object>`-tag doesn't handle as much functions as the `<iframe>`-tag .

[Read more about the  here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attributes)

With `<iframe>` you can use the 'trick' of handling document started position with 'hashtagging' elements to be focused . [And control zoom like this post aswers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2224816/20836041)

Maybe more responsive like this :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Object</title>
<style>
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    outline: none;
    font-family: 'Poppins', 'system-ui', 'sans-serif';
    font-weight: 300;
    transition: .3s linear 0s all;
}
body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
#wrap {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 40vh;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#frame {
    width: 400vw;
    height: 161vh;
}
#frame { zoom: 0.5; -moz-transform: scale(0.5); transform: scale(0.5); -moz-transform-origin: 0 0; transform-origin: 0 0; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
        <iframe id="frame" src="https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#theming"></iframe>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello! Apologies for the late reply, it was Christmas and did Christmasy stuff. Happy Holidays! This solved it. It may not be the solution to the object one but iFrame is the best solution for this. As I am also new to coding, I never thought of using iFrame because object was the first thing I saw on the internet while diving. I've got a long way to go haha. Thank you so much for your help Ed!