# Shrink the Actual Scale of a Google Doc Inside an iFrame

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, scale, google-docs

I need to embed a Google Doc into a web page but with scaling of the Doc.

It's pretty easy to embed a Google Doc using an iFrame (with "Publish to web", i.e. "https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/DOC-ID/pub?embedded=true") but it has proven extremely difficult to adjust its zoom level and scale within the iFrame to fit smaller windows or mobile screens.

There seem to be a million "solutions" online, including here...
[How can I scale the content of an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166160/how-can-i-scale-the-content-of-an-iframe/2224816)
...But I can't find anything that actually adjusts the iFrame itself -AND- adjusts the zoom/scale of a Google Doc within the iFrame. If the iFrame shrinks, I need the scale of the content inside (a Google Doc in this case) to shrink as well.

If the iFrame is set to 100% width, the iFrame adjusts itself when the window is smaller. But the zoom level and scale of the Doc inside does not. Instead, the text in the Doc all just shifts around to fit better, but I don't want this. I need the actual scale to shrink. Is there a way to actually do this? (CSS, JS, it doesn't matter.) Thank you!

P.S. I don't mind up/down scrollbars at all, but don't want side-to-side scrolling.